# Using `case` with range in `switch` statement in Swift

Tags: swift, switch-statement

I'm new to swift, and testing something out in Swift Playgrounds. Trying to use `switch`, but it isn't working. Can someone help me?

```
func loveCal() {
    let loveScore = Int.random(in: 0...100)

    switch loveScore {
    case 80...100:
        print("You love eachother like Kanye loves Kanye")
    case 40...80:
        print("You go together like coke and mentos")
    case 0...40:
        print("You'll be forever alone")
    }
}

loveCal()
```

Comment: What error are you getting in Xcode? You must have a message next to the prints in your playground.

Comment: `switch Int.random(in: 0...100) {
    case 0..<40:
        print("You'll be forever alone")
    case 40..<80:
        print("You go together like coke and mentos")
     default:
        print("You love eachother like Kanye loves Kanye")
    }`

Answer (score 2):

All you are missing is `default` case:

```
// ...
case 0...40:
    print("You'll be forever alone")
default:
    print("This should never happen")
```